# How can I print the contents of an array?

Tags: arrays, assembly, masm

I'm trying to print the contents of an array by using assembly language as below.

I could compile the code, but I could not run it.
How should I fix the code to print the contents of an array?

```
TITLE arrayFill_example (arrayFill_ex.asm)

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
count = 5
array       DWORD        count DUP(?)
arraySize = ($ - array) / 4

.code
; saves the general-purpose registers, retrieves the parameters, and fills the array
ArrayFill   PROC
            push        ebp
            mov         ebp,esp
            pushad                              ; save registers
            mov         esi,[ebp+12]            ; offset of array
            mov         ecx,[ebp+8]             ; array length
            cmp         ecx,0                   ; ECX == 0?
            je          L2                      ; yes: skip over loop

            L1:
            mov         eax,10000h              ; get random 0-FFFFh
            call        RandomRange             ; from the link library
            mov         [esi],ax                ; insert value in array
            add         esi,TYPE WORD           ; move to next element
            loop L1

            L2: popad                           ; restore registers
            pop         ebp
            ret         8                       ; clean up the stack
ArrayFill ENDP

main        PROC
            push        OFFSET array            ; passed by reference
            push        count                   ; passed by value
            call        ArrayFill

            ; for showing array contents
            mov         eax, 0
            mov         esi, array
            mov         ecx, arraySize

            L1:
            mov         eax, array[esi * TYPE array]
            call        WriteInt
            call        Crlf
            add         esi, 4
            loop L1

exit
main        ENDP
END main
```

Specifically this part is not working for me...

```
; for showing array contents
        mov         eax, 0
        mov         esi, array
        mov         ecx, arraySize

        L1:
        mov         eax, array[esi * TYPE array]
        call        WriteInt
        call        Crlf
        add         esi, 4
        loop L1
```

Comment: You mean you *can* run it, but it doesn't do what you want?  Or somehow it actually doesn't run?  Describe your problem in more detail.  See [mcve] and [ask] for tips on writing a good question.

Comment: Use a debugger to single-step through your code and figure out where it stops doing what you expect.  e.g. check that those function calls don't clobber `ecx`?

Comment: @PeterCoedes I would like to print the contents of array like "3, 5, 7, 10, 2".
But the code didn't work like that.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm trying to use a debugger. Then I found the error on "mov         eax, [esi]" in L1 of main PROC.  
The error says "Unhandled exception at 0x00403791 in Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000029E2."
But I have no idea how I can solve the problem. 
Do you have some idea for it ?

Comment: When execution stops there, look at the value in `esi`.  If it's not what you expect, work backwards to see how it got there.  (e.g. set a breakpoint earlier, and single-step while watching registers).

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks, I will try it.

Answer (score 2):

### Problem 1

> ```
> array       DWORD        count DUP(?)
> ```

With this definition the array contains **dwords**. But your program just fills the array with **words** using:

> ```
> mov         [esi],ax                ; insert value in array
> ```

```
add         esi,TYPE WORD           ; move to next element
```

Better write:

```
mov  [esi], eax              ; insert value in array
add  esi, 4                  ; move to next element
```

---

### Problem 2

> ```
> mov         esi, array
> ...
> mov         eax, array[esi * TYPE array]
> ```

These lines are redundantly referring to the array. That's adding a pointer to a pointer, giving the wrong address!  (Or actually, `mov esi, array` loaded the first element, not the address, because that's how MASM syntax works.)

`mov esi, OFFSET array` gives you the address in esi.  From there, `[esi]` is the first element, `array[esi]` is similar to C `array[ (intptr_t)array ]` (but just a byte offset without scaling by the element size).  The resulting address is unlikely to be valid.

Just use one or the other, indexing with small integers, or a pointer increment.  Getting a pointer into a register is usually good, as in:

```
mov  esi, OFFSET array
mov  ecx, arraySize

L1:
mov  eax, [esi]
call WriteInt
call Crlf
add  esi, 4
loop L1
```

Comment: Thanks, it was easy to understand for me. 
After I fixed the code as you say, I found the error on "mov eax, [esi]" in L1 of main PROC again. 

The error says "Unhandled exception at 0x00403791 in Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000029E2." 
But I have no idea how I can solve the problem. 
Do you have some idea for it ?

Comment: @arccycle The Exception stems from the fact that the `ESI` register wasn't actually loaded with the correct address! Since this needs to be **M**ASM code the correct instruction is `mov esi, OFFSET array`. I will also correct Fifoernik's answer. Apparantly he was focussed on **N**ASM style...